# polymorphism results showing in wrong div

Tags: python, html, polymorphism

Everything functions as it should, it's just that the results are being printed into a new  under the footer, when I want it to be in the blank div that starts out saying "Click a link to get started." Any help in the right direction would be righteous, thanks in advance.

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "My Top Fives"
        self.css = "css/boilerplate.css"
        self.css = "css/style.css"
        self._head = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Top Fives</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boilerplate.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        '''
        self._body = '''
        <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <div id="header">
    <img src="images/top_5_logo.png" width="200" height="200"></div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="?link=rush">RUSH</a></li>
        <li><a href="?link=between">Between the Buried & Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="?link=coheed">Coheed & Cambria</a></li>
        <li><a href="?link=deftones">Deftones</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="?link=tool">TOOL</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


#<!-- blank div here -->

<div id="blank"><h2>Click a link to get started.</h2>

</div>
#<!-- footer  div here -->

        <div id="footer">
      <p>&copy; 2014 Top Fives</p></div>
  </div>
</div>'''


        self._close = '''
    </body>
</html>'''


#=========================================== Don't forget getters/setters & polymorphism         =================#

    def print_out(self):
        return self._head + self._body + self._close #overridden by the polymorphism

class ContentPage(Page): #inheritance function (subclass?)
    def __init__(self): #constructor function
        super(ContentPage, self).__init__() #or it can be Page.__init__()
        self._list_inputs = []
        self._list_inputs = ''
        self.num = 0

#==================== getter ========================#
    @property #how we access our inputs
    def inputs(self):
        return self._list_inputs

#==================== setter ========================#
    @inputs.setter
    def inputs(self, arr): #sorts through the "Mega Array" and creates HTML
        self.__inputs = arr #changes private inputs
        for item in arr: #for each item in the array (held in data.py)
            self._list_inputs += item[self.num] # (+= means in addition to)


#============================ polymorphism (from videos) ========================#
    def results(self):
        return self._head + self._body + "<br/ >" + "<div id='blank'><b>Name:</b> "     +self.data.name + "<br>" + "<b>Members:</b> " + self.data.members + "<br>" + "<b>First Release Date:</b> " + self.data.first_release + "<br>" + "<b>Albums:</b> " + self.data.albums + "<br>" + "<b>Genres:</b> " + self.data.genres + "<br>" + "<b>Record Label:</b> " + self.data.label + self._list_inputs + self._close + "</div>"
```

Comment: FWIW, in `ContentPage.__init__()` you first set `self._list_inputs = []` the immediately cancel that out with a `self._list_inputs = ''`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @martineau

Comment: In other words I don't even need    self._list_inputs = []

Comment: A variable can't have two different values (unless it's a container like a `list` or `dict`). I'm not sure, but it looks like you want `self._list_inputs` to be a list based on the rest of your code. You may have to convert it into a string before outputting it though.